# Is it possible to generate email validation token from one website and validate it from other website using asp.net identity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have two websites. One website is responsible to create a user using identity framework like:

```
UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

And then I'm generating email confirmation token like:

```
var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

This is how I'm creating Confirmation link:

```
$"{OtherWebsiteBaseUrlHere}/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId={user.Id}&code={code}";
```

When I open this link, my other website is unable to validate this token and says `Invalid token`.

My other website is also using identity framework and pointing to the same database where my first database is pointing. My question is that...Is it possible to generate validation token from one website and validate it from other website? As per my knowledge, it uses security stamp to validate tokens. If this is true, it should validate token from other website as well because the database is same. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are both websites running on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

As database is same, while validation token is generated, along with the timestamp let it get stored in the table(May be from first website which may be hosted in webserver where database is present)

From second website (which may be hosted in different webserver or same webserver like first), while validating, **let the token be validated against the table data**. i.e. same database means same table, same set of data all are possible. Hence synchronous value can be validated.

Hope that helps!!!